# how to add a div instead of replacing it with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!--css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
<!--css-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script><!--test jquery-->
    function myFunction() {
        var obj = document.getElementById("h01");
        obj.innerHTML = "Hello jQuery";
    }
    onload = myFunction;
</script><!--test jquery fine-->
<script>
$(function(){

    $('#show-back').hide();

    $('#formid').on('click' ,'input[type=radio]', function(){
        if (this.id == "retro" && this.checked) {
            $('#show-back').show();
        } else {
            $('#show-back').hide();
        }
    });

});
$(function (){

    $('#show-sx').hide();

    $('#formid').on('click' ,'input[type=radio]', function(){
        if (this.id == "sx" && this.checked) {
            $('#show-sx').show();
        } else {
            $('#show-sx').hide();
        }
    });

});
$(function(){

    $('#show-dx').hide();

    $('#formid').on('click' ,'input[type=radio]', function(){
        if (this.id == "dx" && this.checked) {
            $('#show-dx').show();
        } else {
            $('#show-dx').hide();
        }
    });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo 'test php' ;
?>
<div id="h01">
</div>

<form action="ricezione.php" method="POST" id="formid">
<p>FRONTE</p>
<p>Seleziona il tipo di personalizzazione che vuoi effettuare sul Fronte della t-shirt.</p>
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampafronte" value="Nessuna Stampa" checked>Nessuna stampa</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampafronte" value="1 colore" id="fronte">Stampa a 1 colore</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampafronte" value="2 colori" id="fronte">Stampa a 2 colore </li> 
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampafronte" value="3 colori" id="fronte">Stampa a 3 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampafronte" value="4 colori" id="fronte">Stampa a 4 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampafronte" value="5 colori" id="fronte">Stampa a 5 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampafronte" value="6 colori" id="fronte">Stampa a 6 colore</li><hr>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampafronte" value="6 colori" id="fronte">Ricamo</li>
</ul>
<span>
<p>RETRO</p>
<p>Seleziona il tipo di personalizzazione che vuoi effettuare sul Retro della t-shirt.</p>
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stamparetro" value="Nessuna Stampa" checked>Nessuna stampa</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stamparetro" value="1 colore" id="retro">Stampa a 1 colore</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stamparetro" value="2 colori" id="retro">Stampa a 2 colore </li> 
    <li><input type="radio" name="stamparetro" value="3 colori" id="retro">Stampa a 3 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stamparetro" value="4 colori" id="retro">Stampa a 4 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stamparetro" value="5 colori" id="retro">Stampa a 5 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stamparetro" value="6 colori" id="retro">Stampa a 6 colore</li><hr>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stamparetro" value="6 colori" id="retro">Ricamo</li>
</ul>
</span>

<p>SPALLA SINISTRA</p>
<p>Seleziona il tipo di personalizzazione che vuoi effettuare sulla spalla sinistra</p>
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampasinistra" value="Nessuna Stampa" checked>Nessuna stampa</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampasinistra" value="1 colore" id="sx">Stampa a 1 colore</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampasinistra" value="2 colori" id="sx">Stampa a 2 colore </li> 
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampasinistra" value="3 colori" id="sx">Stampa a 3 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampasinistra" value="4 colori" id="sx">Stampa a 4 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampasinistra" value="5 colori" id="sx">Stampa a 5 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampasinistra" value="6 colori" id="sx">Stampa a 6 colore</li><hr>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampasinistra" value="6 colori" id="sx">Ricamo</li>
</ul>

<p>SPALLA DESTRA</p>
<p>Seleziona il tipo di personalizzazione che vuoi effettuare sulla spalla destra</p>
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampadestra" value="Nessuna Stampa" checked>Nessuna  stampa</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampadestra" value="1 colore" id="dx">Stampa a 1 colore</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampadestra" value="2 colori" id="dx">Stampa a 2 colore </li> 
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampadestra" value="3 colori" id="dx">Stampa a 3 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampadestra" value="4 colori" id="dx">Stampa a 4 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampadestra" value="5 colori" id="dx">Stampa a 5 colore </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampadestra" value="6 colori" id="dx">Stampa a 6 colore</li><hr>
    <li><input type="radio" name="stampadestra" value="6 colori" id="dx">Ricamo</li>
</ul>
<p>Cambio</p>
<!-- cambio  fronte-->
<div id="show_front">
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="cambio" value="Nessun Cambio" checked>Nessun cambio</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="cambio" value="1colore" >1 colore</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="cambio" value="2colore" >2 colori</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="cambio" value="3colore" >3 colori</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="cambio" value="4colore" >4 colori</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="cambio" value="5colore" >5 colori</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="cambio" value="6colore" >6 colori</li>    
</ul>
</div>
<!-- cambio  fronte fine-->

<!-- cambio  retro-->
<div>
<div id="show-back">
<p> Dietro </p>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_r" value="Nessun Cambio" >Nessun cambio</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_r" value="1colore" >1 colore</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_r" value="2colore" >2 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_r" value="3colore" >3 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_r" value="4colore" >4 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_r" value="5colore" >5 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_r" value="6colore" >6 colori</li>  
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<!-- cambio  sinistra fine -->
<!-- cambio  sinistra-->
<div id="show-sx">
<p>Sinistra</p>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_s" value="Nessun Cambio" >Nessun cambio</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_s" value="1colore" >1 colore</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_s" value="2colore" >2 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_s" value="3colore" >3 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_s" value="4colore" >4 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_s" value="5colore" >5 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_s" value="6colore" >6 colori</li>  
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- cambio  sinistra fine -->
<!-- cambio  destra-->
<div id="show-dx">
<p>Destra</p>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_d" value="Nessun Cambio" >Nessun cambio</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_d" value="1colore" >1 colore</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_d" value="2colore" >2 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_d" value="3colore" >3 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_d" value="4colore" >4 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_d" value="5colore" >5 colori</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="cambio_d" value="6colore" >6 colori</li>  
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- cambio  destra fine -->

<button type="submit">Invia</button>
</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

I searched and read other questions but I solved the problem , if I choose , for example, " sinistra q colore " appears in a div with no choice for the "sinistra " . but even if I choose " destra 1colore " the div is replaced with options to destra. I would add no substitute .how can I do , thanks for the help ,

Answer (score 2):

See [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
Example:

```
$( "#id" ).append( "<div>New div</div>" );
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I read and tried your suggestion but does not solve the problem .. if one chooses for example 1 colore  retro , comes out a div with the options "cambio  " for this choice , but now if I choose also left a color they're out of choices "cambio " for this option , but you change those extras for the back , instead I wish that were added so that if , for example, one makes a different choice for each option ( fronte sinistra dietro destra)
the appear all four options to choose "change "
I hope I was more clear , sorry but my English is not ' good